# How to create a simple doughnut chart

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, svg, charts

I am having a really hard time trying to make a doughnut chart. All the solutions out there are using libraries and I dont want to add a hefty charting library to use just one chart. Also my stack is a little complex and having issues with using libraries. So I am trying to be as lean as possible. Basically I want to create the chart shown below.

[image]

I want to have center text and also be able to change the doughnut data values so needs javascript. I have basically tried to do this in CSS but it fails in IE9. As I understand it I would have to use SVG for this but I am totally new to the subject so can someone tell me how I should get started? Or point me to an example?

Comment: To help your search try making a pie chart and placing a circle on top in front of it.

Comment: some tips here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37206635/circle-with-three-different-border-colors

Comment: See the [duplicate Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23664633/draw-line-start-from-the-center-of-each-sector-in-donut-chart/23664955#23664955) to create a donut chart -- ignore the radial lines that were requested in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try making a pie chart first. 
Then put a white circle on top with your detials inside (total 12000 etc.)
```

An example of a pure CSS pie chart is [here](https://codepen.io/AtomicNoggin/pen/fEish)